# summarize results in SQL nested query with table join

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ms-access, subquery

I have a nested query with an inner join, that returns multiple records for a given "software", but i need to compress the results in one line...
(The output is attached )
for one software, you see multiple records with fields with 'resolved' and 'not resolved', and i need to compress this down to one line, showing resolved - resolved- not resolved, respectively...for example.
but sometimes, the same column will have two or more "Resolved" records. I would like to create a new column, like SPPA2, or WCS2, etc... if that happens, and combine the date for each record in the same column as "resolved", or "not resolved"
I'm pretty newbie, so trying to get my head around the logic.

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT act.Vendor  + ' ' + act.[Application Name] + ' ' + act.Version as "Software name"
                ,act.srmNumber as SRM#
                ,ssd.DateAssign

                ,IIF(ssd.DateResolv IS NOT NULL AND ssd.EntryText LIKE '%Step 1%' AND ssd.TargetUnitID = 48, 'Resolved', 'Not Resolved') as SPPA
                ,IIF(ssd.DateResolv IS NOT NULL AND ssd.EntryText LIKE '%Step 2%' AND ssd.TargetUnitID = 39, 'Resolved', 'Not Resolved') as WCS
                ,IIF(ssd.DateResolv IS NOT NULL AND ssd.EntryText LIKE '%Step 3%' AND ssd.TargetUnitID = 738, 'Resolved', 'Not Resolved') as SAM   
FROM [SAMI_Main].dbo.vw_SAM_Software_Deployment AS ssd INNER JOIN [SAMI_Main].dbo.ACT_Inventory AS act ON act.srmNumber = RIGHT(ssd.callID,7)) AS T1
WHERE t1.SPPA = 'Resolved' OR t1.WCS = 'Resolved' OR t1.SAM = 'Resolved'
;
```

[OUTPUT HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQNkr.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Is this the expected output?

```
|Software Name|SRM#|SPPA|WCS|SAM|

|SAP...|1456484|Resolved 2015-09-22|Not Resolved|Not Resolved|

|Dessci...|1514703|Resolved 2016-01-20|Not Resolved|Not Resolved|

|Adobe Air...|1525807|Resolved 2016-02-11|Not Resolved|Not Resolved|
```

If so, this query might work. I don't have access to SQL Server, so I'm unsure about the syntax:

```
SELECT DISTINCT software_name AS [Software Name],
SRM#,
IIF(SPPA = 'Resolved', 'Resolved' + ' ' + MAX(DateAssign OVER (PARTITION BY software_name, SPPA), 'Not Resolved') AS SPPA,
IIF(WCS = 'Resolved', 'Resolved' + ' ' + MAX(DateAssign OVER (PARTITION BY software_name, WCS), 'Not Resolved') AS WCS, 
IIF(SAM = 'Resolved', 'Resolved' + ' ' + MAX(DateAssign OVER (PARTITION BY software_name, SAM), 'Not Resolved') AS SAM
FROM
(SELECT act.Vendor  + ' ' + act.[Application Name] + ' ' + act.Version as software_name
,act.srmNumber as SRM#
,ssd.DateAssign
,IIF(ssd.DateResolv IS NOT NULL AND ssd.EntryText LIKE '%Step 1%' AND ssd.TargetUnitID = 48, 'Resolved', 'Not Resolved') as SPPA
,IIF(ssd.DateResolv IS NOT NULL AND ssd.EntryText LIKE '%Step 2%' AND ssd.TargetUnitID = 39, 'Resolved', 'Not Resolved') as WCS
,IIF(ssd.DateResolv IS NOT NULL AND ssd.EntryText LIKE '%Step 3%' AND ssd.TargetUnitID = 738, 'Resolved', 'Not Resolved') as SAM   
FROM [SAMI_Main].dbo.vw_SAM_Software_Deployment AS ssd 
INNER JOIN [SAMI_Main].dbo.ACT_Inventory AS act ON act.srmNumber =     RIGHT(ssd.callID,7)) AS T1
WHERE t1.SPPA = 'Resolved' OR t1.WCS = 'Resolved' OR t1.SAM = 'Resolved';
```

I've used the MAX keyword as an analytic function here. I've [written about the MAX keyword](http://www.completeitprofessional.com/oracle-max/) before, but from an Oracle perspective. I understand it works similarly in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the reponse, I cleaned up the syntax on your code using MAX() for SqlServ..
It gave the output as attached...
[OUTPUT HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2A0L.jpg)

so I just need the records compressed to one record, for each software showing each Resolved column with MAX() date as you provided, if that exists in each column... so in the example, it would be "Adobe Air" as one record, with all column "resolved". the other 2 software is what is intended.

```
SELECT DISTINCT software_name AS [Software Name],
```

SRM#,
IIF(SPPA = 'Resolved', 'Resolved' + ' (' + MAX(DateAssign) OVER (PARTITION BY software_name, SPPA) + ')', 'Not Resolved') AS SPPA,
IIF(WCS = 'Resolved', 'Resolved' + ' (' + MAX(DateAssign) OVER (PARTITION BY software_name, WCS) + ')', 'Not Resolved') AS WCS, 
IIF(SAM = 'Resolved', 'Resolved' + ' (' + MAX(DateAssign) OVER (PARTITION BY software_name, SAM) + ')', 'Not Resolved') AS SAM
FROM
(SELECT act.Vendor  + ' ' + act.[Application Name] + ' ' + act.Version as software_name
,act.srmNumber as SRM#
,ssd.DateAssign
,IIF(ssd.DateResolv IS NOT NULL AND ssd.EntryText LIKE '%Step 1%' AND ssd.TargetUnitID = 48, 'Resolved', 'Not Resolved') as SPPA
,IIF(ssd.DateResolv IS NOT NULL AND ssd.EntryText LIKE '%Step 2%' AND ssd.TargetUnitID = 39, 'Resolved', 'Not Resolved') as WCS
,IIF(ssd.DateResolv IS NOT NULL AND ssd.EntryText LIKE '%Step 3%' AND ssd.TargetUnitID = 738, 'Resolved', 'Not Resolved') as SAM
FROM [SAMI_Main].dbo.vw_SAM_Software_Deployment AS ssd 
INNER JOIN [SAMI_Main].dbo.ACT_Inventory AS act ON act.srmNumber = RIGHT(ssd.callID,7)) AS t1
WHERE t1.SPPA = 'Resolved' OR t1.WCS = 'Resolved' OR t1.SAM = 'Resolved' ORDER BY SRM# DESC;